# Air compressor - auto on and off

Tags: switches, air-pressure

What can I add to my air compressor so it automatically turns off when it exceeds a certain pressure, and on when below a certain pressure? Is there a device that I can manually set lower and upper pressures limits that acts as an on off switch?

The compressor does not have a receiver tank - it pumps into a 10 metre hose with a regulator at the end.

Cheers!

Comment: In effect your 10m hose will act as the receiver tank, and with such a tiny "tank" your compressor is going to run like brrrp-brrrp-brrrp as the pressure switch cycles on & off while you're using the air. Any normal compressor pressure switch is going to have its lifetime drastically reduced by being used in such a fashion.

Comment: thanks for your replies @brhans and @Solar Mike! 

I am working out how [this company](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqEHeKudoaY) `code` have their compressor setup...  note how it cycles on and off as the diver breathes. 

From what you've said - a receiver tank would be a worthwhile addition to the setup.

Answer (score 1):

A pressure switch, actually used on compressors to do exactly what you describe, but without a receiver it will cycle very rapidly.

Comment: They make pressure switches for air compressors with built in hysteresis but as @brhans said, with a 10 gal tank the hysteresis isn't doing much.